# Count a date as 1 word PHP

Tags: php, count

I have a sentence like this :

> i am a superhero. @xxxxx August 28, 2016 at 09:29AM

What i want is like this :

```
i = 1
am = 1
a = 1
superhero = 1
@xxxxx = 1
August 28, 2016 at 09:29AM = 1
```

i have succeed to count all of them with this :

```
$string = "i am a superhero, @xxxxx August 28, 2016 at 09:29AM";
$result= array_count_values(explode(' ', $string));
```

But what i want is to count `August 28, 2016 at 09:29AM` as 1 word.
Does it possible ?

Comment: I don't really get what you want, could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: see the updated code

Comment: Is the string always going to have the same format?

Comment: The date what i showing is always like that.

Comment: Just do your array_count_values and then subtract 4, since your date format is always going to be the same and it's 5 items long.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a better pattern, but this could work as an example.

```
$string = "i am a superhero, @xxxxx August 28, 2016 at 09:29AM";
$string = preg_replace('/(\w+) (\d+), (\d+) at (\w+)/i', '$1_$2_$3_$4', $string);
$result= array_count_values(explode(' ', $string));
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Why `preg_replace`?

Comment: It is just replacing the spaces in the date with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

If your date format is always the same then you can subract 4 from the total count.

```
$string = "i am a superhero, @xxxxx August 28, 2016 at 09:29AM";
$result= count(explode(' ',$string))-4;
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
6
```